# In React JavaScript, How to call a class inside another class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, grid, components

I began to learn JavaScript and React these days, I tried to draw some grids in a website and met a problem like this:

Everything works fine when I code like this:

```js
export default class PathfindingVisualizer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nodes: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const nodes = getInitialGrid();
    this.setState({ nodes });
  }

  render() {
    const { nodes } = this.state;
    console.log(nodes);
    return (
      <>
        <p style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>Visualize Algorithms</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div className="node-container">{nodes}</div>  // HERE WORKS FINE
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

And the website turned out to be like this which is fine:

[image]

But when I changed the code like this:

```js
  render() {
    const { nodes } = this.state;
    console.log(nodes);
    return (
      <>
        <p style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>Visualize Algorithms</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <NodeContainer>{nodes}</NodeContainer>  // HERE
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

The grids just disappear, and nothing in `<body>`:

[image]

Could anybody help me? I can't figure out why this is happening.

Class NodeContainer and Node are like this:

```js
export default class NodeContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="node-container"></div>;
  }
}
```

```js
export default class Node extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="node-item"></div>;
  }
}
```

---

Hey, thank you guys for the answers:) this is my first time to ask a question here. I solved the problem by adding {this.props.xxxxx} as you said and it works.
Corrected codes as following:

```
...
        <br />
        <br />
        <NodeContainer nodes={nodes}></NodeContainer> // HERE
      </>
...
```

the NodeContainer class:

```
export default class NodeContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="node-container">{this.props.nodes}</div>; //HERE
  }
}
```

I didn't use 'this.props.children', but will check out later. I skipped the basic tutorial so I didn't understand how to pass params to class, I checked this video to help myself quickly understand this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICmMVfKjEuo&list=PLN3n1USn4xlntqksY83W3997mmQPrUmqM&index=5&t=0s

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to call `children` in`props`

```js
export default class NodeContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="node-container">{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the Node class is being referenced so I'm not sure that's relevant.

Your issue is that the your passing the `nodes` component to the `NodeContainer` component, but not *rendering* it in `NodeContainer`. You should look into how `props` are passed to components - they appear as `this.props.children` on the component. Your code should look like this.

```
 export default class NodeContainer extends Component {
      render() {
        return <div className="node-container">{this.props.children}</div>;
      }
 }
```

If you're wondering how `nodes` appears as `this.props.children`, it's because of how React treats components. You can achieve the same thing by passing it into `children` explicitly as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, in reactJS, there's should be data to be pass from your Parent element to your Children element.
In your case to be able to show the data you want,

1. you need to pass your state from the `<PathFindingVisualizer />` to your `<NodeContainer />`, which you have done it by using node as a children between `<NodeContainer />` tag. And you forget the second step,
2. You need to access the data you have passed inside `<NodeContainer />` class you made. How? just access it by using `this.props.children.`

   here's the example.

```
    export default class NodeContainer extends Component {
      render() {
        return <div className="node-container">{this.props.children}</div>
      }
    }
```

4. Problem solved.

as a reference see this. https://learn.co/lessons/react-this-props-children